# Practical books about lasers

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, laser

Can someone point me towards some good books about laser from a practical/experimental perspective (maybe even a review paper). Most books I found spend a lot of time going through derivations and theoretical concepts. I would like to go deeper into that, too, at a point, but for now I would like to know a bit more about when to use which laser and why in different experimental situations. I am mainly interested in atomic/molecular spectroscopy and I would like to understand better why do they use a given laser in given circumstances (e.g. why use a pulse vs a CW laser, how to scan the frequency of a laser, what is the best way to produce pulsed from CW for a given type of laser). It would be great if you can tell be about some books/papers in which they present actual experiments in which they used a certain laser, not just abstract concepts (which is what most books I found do).

Comment: Philip C. D. Hobbs? https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470466339

Comment: Not a book, but a very useful resource for optics. You can find lots about lasers there. https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html. And if you are actually going to buy a laser, optics companies have engineers that will help.